# Create a mail server w/ CyberPanel on Digital Ocean

Tags: mail

I'm trying to create a mail server on Digital Ocean w/ CyberPanel.
My idea is to host all my email accounts there while having websites on a different server.

I was trying to google how to set up this however there's little to no information on how to do it w/ CyberPanel.

Any advise on how to do this would be appreciated.
I do have a limited knowledge on this one so I would appreciate also advice on how to redirect my DNS records with my domain registrar (Porkbun).

Many thanks!

Comment: Questions here are limited to [operating websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [Advanced server administration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) like setting up email servers is best asked over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), however questions that are [broadly-scoped or asking for tutorials](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) aren't  really a good fit for any Stack Exchange site, which is limited to questions that are specific in nature due to its format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading about CyberPanel, it looks to me like it doesn't have the ability to manage email accounts and receive inbound email. The only resources I can find all relate to outgoing email only.

So, to the best of my knowledge, it is **not possible to use CyberPanel to manage a full-service mail server**. You would need specialized mail server software for that, and for reasons beyond the scope of this answer, 99% of the time it's easier to get a real email provider instead of dealing with the mess that is manual email server administration.

Comment: Thanks Maximillian. Will be going to email hosting providers then.:)